# Are purchased gathering missions usable more than once?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I recently bought a Treasure Hunting mission from the Auction House.  When I used it, I noticed the name of a new mission with a little unlocked lock appear next to it in my Treasure Hunt mission list.

However, once that mission was done, it doesn't appear in my list any more.

Is that mission only doable once, or is there some sort of limit (time or # of missions) before it reappears in my list?

I ask because the loot from said mission was much better than normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. They're one-shots -- that's why they're so highly valued.

Edit to answer question in comment: The best way to find these unlockable missions seems to be the slicing skill -- they show up as loot from bountiful/rich lockboxes sometimes.

Comment: how do you generate them?

Comment: @sarge_smith: They're random drops from world mobs or from other crew skill missions.

Comment: Primarily the Slicing mission.